# Spring method of loading an xml mapping file

Tags: xml, spring

So I have an external xml mapping file that will be loaded in my spring boot application that will be stored in a cache map.

I know I can do it like this:

```
public void loadConfiguration() {
    InputStream stream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("model.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stream);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    // parse it and add to a Hashmap
```

Since I am using Spring Boot, is there a proper spring way to do it? Particularly with loading my xml file as a input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Spring resource abstraction, e.g. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is suitable but I was also able to do it like this as by creating a class with various other methods I would like to declare and call that I can inject the object and call the methods in other areas of my code

```
@Component
public class ConfigManager {

    private final String xmlFile = "something.xml";

    @Autowired
    public ConfigManager(ResourceLoader loader) {
        InputStream is = loader.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xmlFile);
        // do something
    }
}
```

The spring class/object ResourceLoader that is part of a spring application will be injected into the constructor via autowiring annotation. Given that my xml file is also in my package, this code will run and initialize itself upon start up